# How to add JNDI Based on my Config file

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jndi

I have been trying since hours to set up JNDI in my project

My Hibernate file is like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory >
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mypass</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@big-data-3.logti.etsmtl.ca:1521:LOG660</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myTeam</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">teamAlpha</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>

    <mapping resource="Scenariste.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Utilisateur.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Annonce.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Genre.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Location.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Pays.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Personnelfilm.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Clientenretard.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Film.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Forfait.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Employe.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Client.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Personneltournage.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

I'm aware to add JNDI it has to be something similar to this

```
 hibernate.connection.datasource = java:/comp/env/jdbc/test
hibernate.transaction.factory_class = \
    org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class = \
    org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

But how to fill the datasource and factory class and lookup class based on my info? my database name is teamAlpha

I'm using JBOSS pluggin for eclipse , 
Thank you